DB connection error aftrer run Laravel app in Gitlab CI for e2e testing
I'm trying to set up e2e testing of Laravel application in Gitlab CI/CD environment using puppetter js. The problem is that when I start local server and try to open my site in browser I get Postgres error: "SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "host.docker.internal" to address: Name or service not known". At the same time, all local Laravel tests start and pass perfectly. My attempts to add host.docker.internal to hosts led me to the fact that for Postgres. I had to start my own server, and then create a user and so on. Solving one problem gives rise to another and so on endlessly. If I understand correctly, the reason is in the names of services when starting the local server, but I don't understand how to solve this problem. My experience in working with Docker and Gitlab CI/CD is extremely small and I've been trying to solve this problem for several days without any success. Can someone explain what exactly the problem is and how to solve it, I will be very grateful.
.gitlab-ci.yml
Tests:
  stage: Tests
  rules:
    - when: always
  image:
    name: php:8.3.9
  services:
    - postgres:14.7
    - redis
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: landlord_test
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
  script:
    - curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.4/install.sh | bash
    - source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
    - nvm install 16 && nvm use 16
    - chmod +x ./pipelines-config-build.sh
    - ./pipelines-config-build.sh
    - php artisan passport:keys
    - chmod 660 storage/oauth-private.key storage/oauth-public.key
    - php artisan migrate:fresh --path=database/migrations/landlord --database=landlord --seed
    - php artisan tenants:artisan "migrate:fresh --database=tenant --seed"
    - ./vendor/bin/pest -d memory_limit=-1 --configuration phpunit.xml tests/ --compact --coverage
    - ./pipelines-e2e-test-frontend.sh

pipelines-config-build.sh
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/imagick
curl -fsSL https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/archive/06116aa24b76edaf6b1693198f79e6c295eda8a9.tar.gz \
| tar xvz -C "/usr/src/php/ext/imagick" --strip 1
echo "Running apt..."
apt-get update && apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev zlib1g-dev pkg-config \
 libssl-dev openssl libzip-dev libpq-dev unzip postgresql-client libmagickwand-dev python3
pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis
pecl install pcov && docker-php-ext-enable pcov
docker-php-ext-install zip bcmath imagick pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql sockets pcntl
docker-php-ext-enable zip bcmath imagick pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql sockets pcntl
echo 'extension=pcntl.so' >> /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/99-webdeveloper.ini
echo "extension=pcov.so" >> /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/99-webdeveloper.ini
docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql
cp .env.pipelines .env
composer update
composer install
php artisan key:generate
if [ -z ${DB_HOST} ]; then DB_HOST=postgres; fi
psql -h ${DB_HOST} -p 5432 -U postgres -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'tenant_test_2'" \
 | grep -q 1 ||  psql -h ${DB_HOST} -p 5432 -U postgres -tc "CREATE DATABASE enant_test_2"
psql -h ${DB_HOST} -p 5432 -U postgres -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'tenant_test'" \
 | grep -q 1 ||  psql -h ${DB_HOST} -p 5432 -U postgres -tc "CREATE DATABASE tenant_test"

npm install --global yarn
yarn install --ignore-engines && yarn prod

pipelines-e2e-test-frontend.sh
whoami
echo '127.0.0.1 tenant_1.solar.test' >> /etc/hosts
whoami
nohup php artisan serve --host=my-domain.test --port=80 &
apt-get update
apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
npm run test:e2e

Add host.docker.internal to /etc/hosts i received the error error: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
